# disable click on context menu items

Tags: android, xml

i'm tring to disable one item into my context menu. i wrote this:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case MYCASE:
                    if(mBoolean) {
                        item.setEnabled(false);
                        item.setCheckable(false);

                    }
                    break;
```

But the item is always clickable. How can i fix?

Comment: Have you debugged it to see if it actually enters your `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.getItem(2).setEnabled(false);//2 is index of the item
}
```